# WPF MVVM Update Model Using View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a tree structure like this:

```
public class Node
{
    public Node Parent { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
    public NodeValue Item { get; set; }
}
```

And a NodeViewModel like this:

```
    public class NodeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    public Node Node
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
     public NodeViewModel(Node node)
    {
      this.Node = node;
      this._children = new ObservableCollection<NodeViewModel>();
    }

  public string Code { 
      get
      {
          return this.Item.Code;
      }
      set
      {
          this.Item.Code = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("Code"); 
      }
           }

  public Node Parent
  {
      get
      {
          return this.Node.Parent;
      }
      set
      {
          if (value != this.Node.Parent)
          {
              this.Node.Parent = value;
              NotifyPropertyChanged("Parent");
          }
      }
  }

  public NodeValue Item 
  {
      get
      {
          return Node.Item; 
      }
      set 
      {
          this.Node.Item = Item;
      } 
  }
private ObservableCollection<NodeViewModel> _children;

public ObservableCollection<NodeViewModel> Children 
  {
      get
      {
          _children.Clear();
         foreach(var child in Node.Children)
         {
             _children.Add(new NodeViewModel(child));
         }
         return _children;
      }
      protected set
      {
          this._children = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("Children");
      }
  }
```

The problem is the last property because when I want to update the model using view model, for example when I want to add a new node I must update `_children` `ObservableCollection` from `NodeViewModel` and also `Children` `List<Node>` from `Node` class.

If I update only the model the UI does not update because `NotifyPropertyChanged` isn't called and if I update only the view, the changes will be lost because the getter will create another `ObservableCollection` and also the changes are not reflected over the model.

How can I update the model through view model class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whichever way you slice it, the view model needs to fully encapsulate the model.  If you had a "save" command you could just update/recreate the model's collection at that time.

Assuming you don't have a "save" command though, and the model should always reflect the current state of the view model, one option is to subscribe to the `ObservableCollection<T>.CollectionChanged` event and update the underlying collection on the fly.

---

A side note, you most likely also don't want to create a new collection every time `Children_get` is called, and are better off just lazy-loading one you keep around.

Answer (score 0):

ObservableCollection already implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
However it will only work if the count of the collection changes. 
Also why do you want a ViewModel Collection? 
But I think you're looking for this implementation:

```
private ObservableCollection<Node> _children;

public ObservableCollection<Node> Children {
  ...code logic
}
```

Don't forget to handle the changed event